# Find first substring not in map

Tags: matlab

I'm using containers.Map class in Matlab as dictionary and I want to find the first substring (from left to right) that is not in my map.

For example, suppose I have the string **'math'** and my map is something like this

```
key    value
m        1
ma       2
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

So if I start reading from left to right the first substring not in map would be **'mat'**.

The obvious answer that comes to my mind is to loop every char and do some concatenation in order to find the substring that is not in my map using the method **iskey(map, key)** where key is the substring in each iteration.

Is there something more efficient to do this? Maybe some predefined function in matlab or at least a more elegant code.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question!  I can't think of a way which is both more efficient and reasonably simple.  The 'more efficient' way I have in mind consists of rewriting your map as a tree structure so that each iteration of the loop requires a single lookup and one comparison test... Are you just looking for something simple, or is this hindering performance in some way?  The method you've described is simple enough to write as a function, so personally I'd just go with that.

Comment: Can you point us towards what stage you think will take the most time? One possible speedup is that iskey() can search for multiple keys at once. I have no idea how this is implemented, but it is probably not slower than multiple iskey() and could at least save you the loop. In principle if you want to save lookups the datastructure has to be able save time when searching for multiple keys, this might be possible if it is a tree and there is a smart iskey() implementation...

Comment: In fact I'm looking for a more simple way to achieve the same, I'm not quite interested in speed performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this.

map = containers.Map;

```
% Initialise map
map('m') = 1;
map('ma') = 2;
map('burt') = 3;

% Define search string
m = 'math';

% Create cell array element for first 1,2,3... letters of search
ma = repmat(m,length(m),1);
ma = cellstr(char(ma .* tril(ones(length(m)))));

% Find first substring that isn't in map
index = find(~map.isKey(ma),1,'first')
```

Comment: This is quite more elegant than the loop solution, thanks man!